# Ajax needs one more click to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a problem with AJAX and Jquery
After hours of researches I finaly post here.

You can see my problem [directly on my (nonfinished) website](http://aurelienguery.fr/oyeah/indexFR.html)

When you arrive on the page, there is nothing on Accueil (it's normal)

*TRY 1*

**Click on Project =>**

- Triggers Header (normal)
- Send an Ajax Request to load the project page into the main div (normal)
- The ('li') don't start to SlideDown (except if I **click a second time on Project**)

*TRY 2*

**Go to A Propos** => (everything is normal) **Go to Project again** =>

- triggers everything !

*The Code*

Here is the code used to trigger the project slidedown :

```
$('li').livequery(function(){

    var lis = $('#project-container ul').find('li');
    $(lis).each(function(index) {
        var li = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            li.slideDown(400);
        }, 300 * index);
    }); 
});
```

I think it's the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962465/ajax-jquery-needs-one-click-more)

It must be a callback story, where the var are not stored properly or something
but unfortunately I can't get it to work with my page.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you run this code once page is loaded. When I suffer this kind of problems on 90% cases thats is the reason.

Comment: encapsulate your code with `$(document).ready(function{ ..your code... });` you can find it in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). I don't think that is the issue here, but it's best practice to do it anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of the livequery (I don't see any advantage over using the default `.on()` method. ([delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) ofc).

It seems like an obsolete lib to me :)

Another hint. Call the right methods with parameters in staid of defining stuff globally. You will lose sight of what gets changed when and by what if you define everything global like this.

use tripple equal `===` and `!==` to compare. Rather then `==` it will avoid unexpected false positives.

in `function GoToLink () { if (WrapLink == 1) {` you compare a string representing an url that can call a js function with 1. Why?

Why don't you call the ajax method in staid of changing the `window.location` ?

Why do you need an extra ajax library since you use jquery you can just use [jquery's default ajax implemention](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Just a couple of ideas to get you on the right track

***UPDATE:***

use of the on method is described in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), you should use it delegated, meaning you apply it on a parent container and give child with it.

$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
   //do something
});

I overlooked the functionality without passing an event.

```
$('li').livequery(function () {
    var lis = $('#project-container ul').find('li');
    $(lis).each(function (index) {
        var li = $(this);

        setTimeout(function () {
            li.slideDown(400);
        }, 300 * index);
    });
});
```

The easiest way here is using a method and call it when you add a list item.

```
 function slideDownListitems($lis){
     $lis.each(function (i) {  
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).slideDown(400);
        }, 300 * i);
    });
 }
 //when a listitem is added call
 slideDownListitems( $('#project-container ul li') );
```

Nice work for one week JS! I will look at the rest more in depth later and give you an update (working now) grtz

Comment: hey VDP,


First thank you for your answer and for your look in my code. I am new in Jquery and Ajax (have been doing all this since 1 week)


So I have a couple of questions : How do I use .on() instead of livequery ?//What do you mean by : calling the right methods?//Ok for the comparisons//In function GoToLink() => I made this stuff to compare the old value of WrapLink to the new one. This way, it avoids page reload if the user is clicking on the same link again.//Why don't I use ajax... because window.location was the first solution I came across. Thanks for everything !

Comment: Thanks for everything ! you're realy cool !
And Thank you for the compliment
I'm trying to modify my functions but it's more complicated that it seems ^^

Comment: and btw, i have been testing the ajax call, the modified slidedownfunction, and I can't get them to work :(